# Issue with prepopulating ng-bootstrap's typeahead whilst relying on model driven forms

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, ng-bootstrap

Suppose I have the following model driven form:

```
this.addressForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  address: this.formBuilder.group({
    placeId: [this.address.placeId],
    description: [this.address.description]
  })
});
```

And the following template:

```
<form [formGroup]="addressForm" (ngSubmit)="updateAddress()" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text"
         formControlName="address"
         placeholder="Type in you address"
         [ngbTypeahead]="chooseAddress"
         [inputFormatter]="addressFormatter"
         [resultFormatter]="addressFormatter"
         autocomplete="off"
         class="form-control">
    </div>
   ...
</form>
```

the addressFormatter:

`addressFormatter = param => param.description;`

Say the `address` is an object with two properties: `placeId` and `description`.

It seems impossible to deal with a `formGroup` (here the `address`) instead of a `formControl` ( here the `address.placeId`) and still pre populate the form with one of the object's properties (e.g. `address.description`).

I get the following error:

> Error in ./UserAccountAddressComponent class UserAccountAddressComponent - inline template:8:9 caused by: control.registerOnChange is not a function
>   TypeError: control.registerOnChange is not a function

I was not able to display one property of the object in the field (the `address.description`) and use another one when I submit the form (`address.placeId`) while still being able to prepopulate the form with one of the object properties (here the `address.description`).

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the way I specified my reactive form.

Changing from:

```
this.addressForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  address: this.formBuilder.group({
    placeId: [this.address.placeId],
    description: [this.address.description]
  })
});
```

...to:

```
this.addressForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  address: this.formBuilder.control({//Notice the control() method instead of group() method
    placeId: this.address.placeId,
    description: this.address.description
  })
});
```

...allowed my to specify an object type instead of a string type for the whole input control. See official angular documentation for **FormBuilder control()** method here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormBuilder-class.html#!#control-anchor

**edit**: Please note that this has nothing to do with the ng bootsrap framework.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your error means the component binded with your input does not implements [ControlValueAccessor interface](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/14ee75924b6ae770115f7f260d720efa8bfb576a/modules/%40angular/forms/src/directives/control_value_accessor.ts). Try to add a `[formControl]` binding to your input :

```
<form [formGroup]="addressForm" (ngSubmit)="updateAddress()" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text"
         formControlName="address"
         [formControl]="addressForm.address"
         placeholder="Type in you address"
         [ngbTypeahead]="chooseAddress"
         [inputFormatter]="addressFormatter"
         [resultFormatter]="addressFormatter"
         autocomplete="off"
         class="form-control">
    </div>
   ...
</form>
```

Comment: typo? `[formControl]="adressForm.adress"`

Comment: @Karbos: Thanks a lot for your input. Can you please explain what the `[formControl]` binding is going to achieve and compare it to the `formControlName` attribute?

Comment: @stealththeninja: I noticed the typo and have changed to "address". Thanks to you too.

Comment: @karbos Can you please also say what component you are referring as "the component bound to my input"?